# How do I set the recipient and body of a message as an NSString property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app will send an SMS when the user asks and the composing view pops up.
I am able to use this code to do this and set a hard-coded number and message as the default:

```
[self sendSMS:@"messageTextGoesHere" recipientList:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phoneNumberGoesHere", nil]];
```

and

```
- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
    controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
    controller.recipients = recipients;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }    
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But what I want to do is set the recipient and message to an NSUserDefaults string. This is what I tried:

```
NSString *messageNumbers = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];
NSString *textMessage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"messageText"];
[self sendSMS:textMessage recipientList:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:messageNumbers, nil]];
```

Instead of the usual popup message composer, it hangs for a moment and then the screen goes black so you have to quit the app. The console gives me this:

```
2013-10-27 17:29:45.428 *APP*[4006:60b] <CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController: 0x1844fb90> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose
2013-10-27 17:29:45.936 *APP*[4006:60b] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <ViewController: 0x14e02700> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

Can somebody please tell me what i've done wrong or whether I need to use different code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using objectForKey, you could try stringForKey.  objectForKey returns an (id) and it is probably not being cast to a string as you are expecting.

```
NSString *textMessage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"messageText"];
```

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you sir for your help.